# Repeated lines inside a column - python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, rows

I recently started using python and now pandas to read excel files. I'm kind of stuck with a question that I didn't find any similar examples.

Let's say that I have data from different machines for different minutes. What happens is that there's multiples informations for one machine. In the figure below for example, there's 5 informations for 5 five minutes regarding to Cost and Temperature if considering the machine 13.5.

I need the average to this information of Cost, Temperature and minutes, that is, only one line for each machine.Considering again the machine 13.5 as example, I need only one output for the cost, that would be 34,4(34+35+35+35+33/number of machines 13.5). Below is my code.

```
         import pandas
         df = pandas.read_excel('Model.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
         df
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `df.head(14)` and explain how to obtain 34.4?

Comment: take a loog at groupby: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) selecting the column to group by followed by a call to `mean()`

so you would do `df.groupby(['M']).mean()`

While a simple usage can group by a single column, you can group by multiple columns or use mappings and functions to determine the grouping. You're also not limited to just using `mean()`. You can use `sum()` among other computations.

Here is a more thorough guide in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html